# Proposal to create Archiving tag and merging self-archiving tag to it

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

By searching the website for the term [Archive](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=archive%20is%3Aquestion), we have about 41 questions in which the archiving (directly or indirectly) is being questioned. However, in most of these posts we don't have any precise tag about archiving at all.

On the other hand, the only existing tag about archiving is [self-archiving](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-archiving) which is awarded to only two questions none of which are really about *self*-archiving and also, the tag does not have any excerpt and wiki.

Here is the proposal:

> Creating [archiving](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archiving) or [archive](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archive) tag and merging the existing [self-archiving](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-archiving) tag into it.

Some example questions which are eligible to the [archive](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archive) tag:

1. [How to archive an academic blog or website?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1655/how-to-archive-an-academic-blog-or-website)
2. [ePrint Archive for PhD Dissertation in the Social Sciences](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/eprint-archive-for-phd-dissertation-in-the-social-sciences)
3. [Archiving papers, simulation and experimental data, etc?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8359/archiving-papers-simulation-and-experimental-data-etc)

If you like the idea, please also include an excerpt and wiki into your answer posts; otherwise, please mention why this proposal is not benefitial to Academia.SE.

Comment: Can you identify specific questions that would benefit from an 'archive' tag? Or at least describe its potential scope in words? Right now this proposal does *not* explain why we need such a tag, what it would be for, and especially, how it would be different from tags like [tag:repository] and [tag:digital-libraries]

Comment: @ff524 I added example questions for the tag proposal.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'archive' is used in a few ways on Academia:

- as a synonym for [repository](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repository), a place to which one can upload code, manuscripts, data, or other materials for storage.
- as a synonym for [digital-libraries](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-libraries), a curated collection of publications.
- in reference to an 'archival publication', where 'archival' denotes that the paper is published, referenceable, and retrievable. We've had a couple of questions on this one, I don't think we'll get many more; I definitely don't think it needs a new tag.

Multi-purpose words like 'archive' are **bad** for tags because then the tags end up with a high level of entropy. That is, the tag is not useful for discriminating "questions about one thing" (whatever that *thing* may be).

Of the two questions currently tagged [self-archiving](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-archiving), one refers to the [digital-libraries](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-libraries) meaning and one to the [repository](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repository) meaning.

The other questions you mention all mean 'archive' in the sense of a [repository](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repository).

It doesn't seem we need a new tag for any of these, since we already have [repository](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repository) and [digital-libraries](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-libraries).

Comment: Maybe it is better to edit the [tag:self-archiving] excerpt and wiki, instead of creating or merging tags as proposed in this question.

Comment: @Enthusiastic why? It's a bad tag. It doesn't carry useful meaning and it should go away. In fact, it was already on my list of retags to do; I just haven't done it yet because I'm [spacing out retags so as not to flood the front page](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1246/suggestions-for-avoiding-disruption-when-retagging)

Comment: At least we should have one tag for related questions. What tag should a person use, if he wants to ask a question about storing a webpage, paper, etc on his own laptop?

Comment: @Enthusiastic Definitely not 'archive', since that's not a common usage of the word! I'm not aware of any questions like that, so I can't comment further on what an appropriate tag might be

Comment: We should definitely think about a good tag for such usages.

Comment: @Enthusiastic can you identify such questions? I'm not aware of any, and if there are none, we probably don't need to worry about a tag for them yet

Comment: we have many examples on [this search list](http://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=archive%20is%3Aquestion) as stated in the question.

Comment: @Enthusiastic as far as I can tell, those are mainly about [tag:repository] or [tag:digital-libraries]; if there's a substantial number that isn't, you should edit your post to list those.